# Sql server 2008 R2 - synchronization of two databases

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two databases with the same schema.
Database A : Production database
Database B : Test database

Database B contains outdated data and I want to synchronize it with the Database A.
I want all the data from Database A in DataBase B .

How can I do that without having to create a new database or detach the production database.

Comment: Create a backup from Database A, then restore it on Database B?

Comment: Hmm..actually the database is really large and I want to synchronize only certain tables from the database. Am I able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backup on the source server and then you can restore it on the destination server. (Please note, that all custom settings will be reseted on the destination).

If you do not want to restore all tables, then you can either build some SSIS packages which packages syncronize the tables. (Build one package per table based on a template package) or you can create a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) on the destination server and write some stored procedures to sync the tables.

If you are familiar with SPs and dynamic queries, you can write an SP, which dynamically builds the syncronization query based on the table's meta data.

Another option is to use a third party software like [Red Gate's SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

It is easy to schedule SSIS packages and SPs so if you want to run the sync based on a schedule, choose these options.